# Uploadifive -- onQueueComplete Not Working Correctly; Options to Limit Queue and File Sizes Also Not Working

Tags: uploadify

I am using Uploadifive to handle file uploads. My (extremely standard) configuration is as follows:

```
<form>
<div id="queue"></div>
<div ><input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true"></div>
<div class="uploadifive-button"><a  href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a></div>
</div>        
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $timestamp = time();?>

$(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'             : false,
    'checkScript'      : 'check-exists.php',
    'formData'         : {'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                  'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                 },
    'queueID'          : 'queue',
    'removeCompleted'  : true,
    'queueSizeLimit'   : 10,
    'uploadLimit'      : 0,
    'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {function goes here},                'onQueueComplete'  : function() { location.reload(); }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I've got 2 problems:

1. The options for `uploadLimit` and `queueSizeLimit` don't seem to work. I can only upload 2 files at a time. If I upload more than 2, the upload works, but I get a lot of popups (generated from check-exists.php) saying the file already exists on server, do I want to replace it.
2. The `onQueueComplete` function seems to run for each file upload, rather than once after all uploads are complete. I.e., if I'm uploading 10 files, the page refreshes 10 times.

I'm running the latest version of Firefox, I'm using jquery version 1.4.4, and Firebug reports no problems.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late to answer this question, but it could help someone else. I got my way around file upload size limit by using '[onAddQueueItem](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/onaddqueueitem/)' event. Here is the code snippet.

```
var bytesLoaded = 0;
$("#file_upload").uploadifive({
    ....
    'onAddQueueItem' : function(file) {
        bytesLoaded += file.size;
        //setting maximum upload to 20MB
        if(bytesLoaded > (20*1024*1024)){
            alert"The file uploaded is greater than 20MB.");
            cancel(); //cancel button ensures the upload is not done
        }
    }
});
```